# Can I change View to the ViewController when click the TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C.

It has `TableViewCell` and the `TableView` on the `ViewController` like the following picture.

[image]

I want to change the View to another `Viewcontroller` when I click the `TableViewCell`.

But it seems can not use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` to change the `View` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` without using `UINavigationController` , The error log like the following:

```
Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

Is there has another way to change the View to another `Viewcontroller` when I click on the `TableViewCell` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface Builder(storyboard) click the following:

[image]

Exactly what the debugger says: `Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'` Then you'll be able to push segues.

Answer (score 1):

U can present view controller using this

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    yourViewController *vc = [[yourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] ];  
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

Comment: It got the error `Expected identifier` at `yourViewController *vc = [[yourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] ];`. Do you know why the error happened ?

Comment: #import "yourViewController"